# Nextjs: can I use ISR to update nav in layout

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

My web app have a `Layout`. In this layout have a `Nav`. The `Nav` can be changed in future(base on `database`).

I need this `Nav` for **SEO**. If I use SSR, some page is complicated and I don't want use SSR.

Is posible to do that?